# Is it possible to set ID and Class of an element using jQuery method attr()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, attr

```
$("selector").attr("id","idname");
```

Is it possible to use above for setting ID or Class of an element.

Comment: In your code you are setting the attribute?!

Comment: what do you want to do exactly. if you want to get id attribute you can simply write $(".class").attr("id");

Comment: Use find method jquery

Comment: Your code works to set the ID attribute http://jsfiddle.net/voyrfyzv/ but your question is unfortunately sparse and lazy.

Comment: i am asking that it is right or wrong?

Comment: how to sent the id value in that attr() method can you give with the example..

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, I know it might seem that some of use have super powers and practice reading people's minds but then again most of us are mere mortals and can only understand what is actually written in the question!  You talk about lists, attributes and ID's What is it you actually want?

Comment: okay i want that to take the value of list(that has an id) using attr() method in jquery.

Answer (score -1):

hm i feel like i've said it thousands of times. The jQuery class selector returns an array of all HTML elements with that class. So, if you want to get data form those elements you need to loop over the array or access it directly.

```
$('.gg1').first().attr("id"); //returns the id of the first element with class gg1
$('.gg1')[1].attr("id"); //returns the id of the second element with class gg1

for(var i = 0; i < $('.gg1').legth; i++= {
  console.log($('.gg1')[i]); } //loops over the cormplete HTML Collection
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

http://www.google.com